# Triplet Loss function exhibiting anomalous behaviour

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am training a person ReID model on a custom dataset using the following architecture
ResNet(50) --> Linear(2048, 512) --> BatchNorm --> Linear(512, num_classes=1000 with bias=False)

The following loss functions are used:

1. Triplet Loss with margin = 0.3 after the first Linear layer
2. Classification loss with label smoothing after the second Linear layer.

The following parameters are used for training:

1. Batchsize = 64
2. Negative semihard mining was used for the first 5 epochs followed by BatchHardMining.
3. lr = 0.0003

The following are the graphs for Triplet Loss and Classification Loss
[image: Classification Loss]
[image: Triplet Loss]

Triplet Loss moves to zero very quickly while the classification loss takes quite a long time. While evaluating the model, I find that it doesn't perform well on testing data. Any inputs would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be due to the high learning rate.
How about lowering the learning rate to 0.0001?
If the learning rate is high, the learning rate is reduced by about 1/3. For example, (0.01, 0.003, 0.001, 0.0003 ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot @core_not_dumped. Lowering the learning rate did the trick. However, I ran into another issue while increasing the number of classes. I have updated the question to reflect the same. Any and all inputs from you would be most helpful.